# I'm struggling to import remotely hosted GeoJSON data via URL as a layer in Leaflet (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I can't get GeoJSON data from a URL to work properly.

I'm trying to create an overlay layer in Leaflet consisting of US counties, and this is what I have done to do so:

```
        var overlays = {
            "Counties": L.geoJson('https://github.com/zeke/us-counties/blob/master/county.geo.json?raw=true', {async: true}).on('loaded', function(e) {map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }
        )}

        // This adds all layers together.
        L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(map);
```

But it doesn't work at all. The JS console error Looks like this:

[image: JS console error]

Is there any good way to get this working?

Comment: Do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

`L.GeoJSON` don't support request, you need to first to load your data manually or use a library like [Leaflet.Ajax](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax)

```
var overlays = {
            "Counties": L.geoJson.ajax('https://github.com/zeke/us-counties/blob/master/county.geo.json?raw=true').on('data:loaded', function(e) {map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
            }
        )}
```